# Remove rows where person data is about is listed in another excel document

Tags: excel, loops

I'm trying to help the City of Seattle process my records requests for listing of employees with hourly salary and supervisor as quickly as possible. What they've discovered is there is one employee in particular they think could be seriously harmed if her domestic violence attacker knows she works at the city. I don't have any experience programming Excel. I request this list a lot in order to get a current organization chart to make available to the public. I only know Python and Javascript which I why I asked here to get help figuring out exactly what VBA I need to know. I would like to know how to programmatically loop through each row and remove it if employee name in employees_to_redact_from_hr_data_pdr.xls so that the city can give me the list in days instead of months.

Comment: To compare two files / sheets just use `if Workbooks("source").Worksheets("sourcesheet").cells(1,1).value2 = Workbooks("destination").Worksheets("destinationsheet").cells(1,1).value2 then`. Afterwards, you just need a loop and you're done: http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_for_loops.html

Comment: The most frequently used language to process excel data is VBA, I suggest that instead of looking for a Python or Javascript solution you get acquainted with VBA

Comment: @ImranAli I updated my question to say "I only know Python and Javascript which I why I asked here to get help figuring out exactly what VBA I need to know."

Comment: @TimClemans please look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377197/iterating-through-populated-rows-in-excel-using-vba)