# Moving folders to another directory

Tags: excel, vba, directory, filesystems, move

I recently posted a question here about moving files to another directory ([Moving files to another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375463/moving-files-to-another-directory/60376359?noredirect=1#comment106842076_60376359)), now I want to move folders, which will then be archived.

The layout is the same with the existing folder in A, target in B and a column C to confirm if completed.

[image: image example]

Code provided was

```
Sub move_files()
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Err.Clear
            On Error Resume Next
            Name (.Cells(i, 1)) As .Cells(i, 2) & "\" & StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(.Cells(i, 1)), "\")(0))
            If Err = 0 Then .Cells(i, 3) = "YES" Else .Cells(i, 3) = "NO"
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Given I am trying to move an entire column, does anyone know if the above can be adapted to move the folder as it only currently works for files. I have searched online but is usually only for one file.

Comment: Did you do any research? I mean if you google for *"vba move folder"* you find tons of examples how to move complete folders. Also there is the [MoveFolder method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/movefolder-method) in the [FileSystemObject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object). Read them carefully and give it a try yourself. If you get stuck or errors show the code you have tried. Otherwise this is just asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: Far too much, there are ones that can move folders, but not so much from a list and have to specify paths, so not good for thousands of files. Also none I could see showing error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a revised version moving folders only. Hopefully it will work.

```vb
Sub move_folders()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim oFSO As Object
  Dim sep As String

  Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      Err.Clear
      If Left(StrReverse(.Cells(i, 2)), 1) = "\" Then sep = "" Else sep = "\"
      On Error Resume Next
      oFSO.MoveFolder .Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2) & sep & StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(.Cells(i, 1)), "\")(0))
      If Err = 0 Then .Cells(i, 3) = "YES" Else .Cells(i, 3) = "NO"
      On Error GoTo 0
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: man that was quick thankyou! I don't quite understand the FSO part but will do some more reading over the weekend and see if I can figure it out. 

Thanks a bunch
Scott