# Looping through the rows until last row

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am new to VBA and I have an excel sheet as shown in the image below and I want to run through each row until the last row to remove the characters in front of "/".

[image: Excel Sheet Example]

The following is my VBA code. However, my code could only work on one cell currently and I am not sure how do I change it to a For Loop to run through all the rows until the last row. Also, there are certain cells that does not contain the "/" and I just want it to be an empty cell. I need some help on how could I work on this? Thank you really appreciate if anyone would be able to assist me with this.

```
Sub String()
' String
Dim stringOriginal As String
stringOriginal = Range("A2").Value

Dim indexOfThey As Integer
indexOfThey = InStr(1, stringOriginal, "/")

Dim finalString As String
finalString = Right(stringOriginal, Len(stringOriginal) - indexOfThey)

Range("A2").Value = finalString

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through populated rows in Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377197/iterating-through-populated-rows-in-excel-using-vba)

Comment: @braX Hello the example you gave consists of rows and columns but I just need it to iterate through a specific column how would I be able to do that?

Comment: There are plenty of other examples here. Did you try searching for it yourself first?

Comment: No VBA code required... Ever heard of `Text To Columns`?

Comment: And if you want VBA code then you can simply record a macro using Text To Columns. BTW From ABC/DEF what do you want? ABC or DEF? For 123, I guess you want a Blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following sub

```
Sub StringOperation()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Rng In Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    If (InStr(1, Rng, "/")) > 0 Then
        Rng = Right(Rng, Len(Rng) - InStr(1, Rng, "/"))
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

***Edit:*** To empty cells that doesn't contain `/` use below codes.

```
Sub StringOperation()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Rng In Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        If (InStr(1, Rng, "/")) > 0 Then
            Rng = Right(Rng, Len(Rng) - InStr(1, Rng, "/"))
              Else
            Rng = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello I would like to make the cell empty if the original one doesn't contain a "/" character how would I be able to do that?

Comment: That's what his example shows you... see how he is using the `Instr` function?

Comment: @JinWei You just need to add `Else` branch to `IF` statement like  `Else Rng = ""`. See edited answer.

Comment: Alright thank you. Another question would be if I want to add "Test" infront of the current string that I have how do I do that? And it will still be empty for those empty cells.

Comment: @JinWei Then change this line `Rng = Right(Rng, Len(Rng) - InStr(1, Rng, "/"))` to `Rng = "Test" & Right(Rng, Len(Rng) - InStr(1, Rng, "/"))`

Comment: @JinWei If you found this answer useful then consider accepting it. Tick as green. Also `Upvote` encourage users.

Comment: Hello I would like to ask if I have 2 columns with values (13-15 JULY, 3-4 AUG) I would like to change it to just 13-07-2020 and 03-08-2020 how do I do that?

Comment: @JinWei Please ask an separate question with your sample data and expected output. This can be done with excel formula and no need `VBA`.