# How to Loop Through A Table Column to Filter Another Table to Send Each Filtered Table By Email?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to:

- Use a value from Table A (column - person's name) to filter on Table B in separate sheet
- Copy filtered Table B into the body of an email (outlook)
- Send outlook email to email address for that recipient (from Table A)
- Loop through the process again for the next person in Table A

Example of Table A:
[image]

Example of Table B:
[image]

So for example for the first iteration

- Take Dave Jones from Table A and filter Table B for Dave Jones.
- Copy the filtered Table B to the body of a new email
- Send to Dave Jones (davejones@davejones.com).
- Return to Table A for the next entry, in this case Anne Smith, and do the same. Repeat until the end of Table A.

I made code for setting up an email but this takes the whole worksheet and does not do any filtering. I am unable to work out how to put this loop together for multiple emails:

```vb
Sub SendWorkSheet_SENDEMAILS1()
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFormat As Long
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Select Case Wb.FileFormat
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbook:
        xFile = ".xlsx"
        xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled:
        If Wb2.HasVBProject Then
            xFile = ".xlsm"
            xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Else
            xFile = ".xlsx"
            xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        End If
    Case Excel8:
        xFile = ".xls"
        xFormat = Excel8
    Case xlExcel12:
        xFile = ".xlsb"
        xFormat = xlExcel12
    End Select
    FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    FileName = Wb.name & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Wb2.SaveAs FilePath & FileName & xFile, FileFormat:=xFormat
    With OutlookMail
        .to = "EMAIL ADDRESS HERE"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Suppliers"
        .HTMLBody = "Hi all," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please find attached etc. etc." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Kind regards," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Sender"
        '.Body = ""
            .Attachments.Add Wb2.FullName
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    Wb2.Close
    Kill FilePath & FileName & xFile
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need to do any filtering. For each name in Table A, do a `VLOOKUP` to Table B and send the email to the recipient from Table A w/the corresponding parameters in Table B.  Right?

Comment: Hi Marc, that could work. I am unsure of how to get the loop to work when including the lookups and the emails for each iteration.

Comment: And how to incorporate multiple rows from Table B for each recipient

Comment: Understood. I'm just saying I would encourage you to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377197/iterating-through-populated-rows and some research about `vlookup()`. You might be able to work it out yourself before someone has time or inclination to work it out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve had the need to do the task you describe a number of times in the past, and the following was the solution I came up with.  Great credit to Sigma Coding at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlInSp0-MdU&ab_channel=SigmaCoding
for providing the bulk of the code – the Loop and Filter stuff I added for my own specific application.

*For the following to work, you need to enable a couple of references within VBA.  In the VBA Editor, select Tools/References & check the boxes ‘Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library’ and ‘Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library’.  If they’re not already checked, you’ll find them listed alphabetically.*

The following code suggestion assumes the following:

•   The Managers’ list is on Sheet1 and the range they are contained in is called “MyRange”

•   The table to filter is on Sheet2 and starts from cell A1

This code works for me – let me know how you go with it.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Outlook As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OutInspect As Outlook.Inspector
Dim EmailTo As String

Dim OutWrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim OutWrdRng As Word.Range
Dim OutWrdTbl As Word.Table

Dim rng As Range, c As Range, MyRange As Range, myFilter As String

Sub TestEmail()

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("MyRange")

    myFilter = c.Value
    EmailTo = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
    
    Sheet2.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & myFilter
    
'ERROR TRAP 
If EmailTo = "" Or Sheet2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count = 1 Then
    GoTo Missing:
End If

    Set rng = Sheet2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error Resume Next

Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Set Outlook = New Outlook.Application
    End If
    
Set OutMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With OutMail
            .To = EmailTo
            .Subject = "Suppliers"
            .Body = "Please find attached etc."
                       
            .Display
            
            Set OutInspect = .GetInspector
            Set OutWrdDoc = OutInspect.WordEditor
            
            rng.Copy
            Set OutWrdRng = OutWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
                OutWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            
            Set OutWrdRng = OutWrdDoc.Paragraphs.Add
                OutWrdRng.InsertBreak
            
            OutWrdRng.PasteExcelTable Linkedtoexcel:=True, wordformatting:=True, RTF:=True
            
            Set OutWrdTbl = OutWrdDoc.Tables(1)
            
                OutWrdTbl.AllowAutoFit = True
                OutWrdTbl.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
            
            .Send
            
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheet2.AutoFilterMode = False
        
        End With

Missing:
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: The only slight issue (other than general formatting which is simple) is that when I expand this to a larger table I am getting a number of emails which have no "To" and a table with just headers. Is there an easy way of removing these blank emails or avoiding them from appearing in the first place? I have tried "If .To = "" Then olMailItem.Close" which is very crude and hasn't worked

Comment: Seems to generate an extra email for each iteration as it alternates between one with content/to and then one without. When I was using it on the exact example above it only produced one content-less email at the end of the run. Strange!

Comment: I’ve added an Error Trap to the code (see above) which should capture any instance of where a record cannot be found – hopefully, this will fix the problem.  Copy the 3 lines of code below ‘ERROR TRAP to your sub – placing them immediately below where you set the filter – AND add `Missing:` to your code immediately before `Next c`.  This should fix the problem – if not, unfortunately I’d have to get the original file to go any further with this.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much. Really great solution overall Kevin!

Comment: How can I resize the columns in the output table? Seems to cause a lot of the cell content to spill onto multiple lines as the columns are too narrow... tried playing around with the AutoFitBehavior but no luck

Comment: @djj1994 Do you mean in the email itself?  If so, I'm not getting the same issue when I try it.  If that's the case, the only thing I can think of would be the `AutoFit` options.  Sorry I can't be of any more help.